# Expand div vertically

Tags: css, html

I have simple problem with divs. I would like to create one big div ("container") which cover whole screen and put into it two other divs ("A" and "B"). "A" has 200px height and I would like "B" to cover remaining space like on picture on the left. Below I paste my code but it doesn't work correctly, because "B" is also outside "container" like on picture on the right. Does anyone know how expand "B" to cover remaining space in "container" like on picture on the left? I would be grateful for the answer.

[image: What I want to get]      [image: Result produced by my code]

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel=stylesheet href="style.css" type="text/css" media=screen>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="A">text</div>
    <div id="B">text</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
#container {
    border-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#A {
    border-color: green;
    height: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
}

#B {
    border-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#A, #B, #container {
    border-style: solid;
    border-size: 1px;   
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/S27an/ here its ran very nice, what problem is this.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the 'conflicting absolute positioning' technique like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/TjArZ/

```
#container {
  border-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}

#A {
  border-color: green;
  height: 200px;
}

#B {
  border-color: red; 
  position:absolute;
  top:204px;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

#A, #B, #container {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px;   
}​
```

The basic idea is that the divs are stretched to the coordinates you specify. Background [here on ALA](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/conflictingabsolutepositions/).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#A {
    border-color: green;
    height: 200px;
    position:relative;
    top:0;left:0;
}

#B {
    border-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
    top:200px;left:0;bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
#container {
border-color: blue;
width: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
}

#A {
border-color: green;
height: 200px;
min-height: 200px;
max-height: 200px;
}

#B {
border-color: red;
height: 100%;

}

#A, #B, #container {
border-style: solid;
border-size: 1px;   
}
```